# Disable keyboard spacebar key type in JFXTextField

Tags: javafx, keyboard, textfield, detection

I need to disable the space in a JFXTextField.
I´m using the following code:

```
...
@FXML
private JFXTextField valueTextField;

valueTextField.setKeyListenerForSpace();

private void setKeyListenerForSpace(){

    valueTextField.setOnKeyPressed( (event) -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
            System.out.println("Spacebar key detected!");
            event.consume();
        }
    });

}
```

Although the program detects the spacebar key being pressed it is typing a space in the textfield.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setOnKeyPressed()` is an event handler setter; you need an event filter, which will intercept this key pressed event at event capturing stage, preventing this control from receiving this event during event bubbling stage.

```
valueTextField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        System.out.println("Spacebar key detected!");
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

For more information read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm).

Comment: Still not working :-(. Spacebar is detected but it is still being typed in the textfield.

Comment: @user6127833 See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424619/javafx-textfield-how-to-prevent-key-from-getting-typed-in-keypressed-event).

Comment: Yes!, that worked like a charm. Thank you very much Jai! I you add the link to the question as an answer I can accept it as correct.

Comment: It's better to mark this question as duplicate. It'll help more people in the long run :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume the `KEY_TYPED` events for the space character in a event filter, since this kind of event is responsible for modifying the `text` property:

```
valueTextField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, evt -> {
    if (" ".equals(evt.getCharacter())) {
        System.out.println("space typed");
        evt.consume();
    }
});
```

`valueTextField.setKeyListenerForSpace();` should yield a compile time error though.

Answer (score 0):

If space key is detected, remove the space:

```
valueTextField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
            valueTextField.setText(valueTextField.getText().substring(0, valueTextField.getLength()-1));
        }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution but it actually is typing the space in the text field. What I want is to disable it.