# Why every KeyEvent is successfully captured except KEYCODE.ENTER in my JavaFX Calculator app?

Tags: javafx, keyevent

I'm writing a simple calculator app with JavaFX. Every keyboard event is successfully captured except the ENTER key. The EQUALS ("=") is the only hardware key that will trigger the calculation function. I have scoured every question on this site that even remotely deals with with keyboard event handling, I have pored over the documentation on Oracle's site to no avail. below is are some excerpts from my code (I left out most of the lines that check every possible KeyCode for brevity):

```
@FXML
private void handleKeyboardEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    KeyCode keyCode = event.getCode();
    if (event.getCharacter().equals("\r") || event.getCharacter().equals("\n")) {
        onEqualsButtonPressed();
    }
    switch (keyCode) {
        case ESCAPE:
            textFieldDisplayEquation.clear();
            textFieldDisplayResult.clear();
            break;

case EQUALS:
    if (event.isShiftDown()) {
        if (textFieldDisplayEquation.getText().length() == 0) {
            textFieldDisplayEquation.clear();
            break;
        } else {
            textFieldDisplayEquation.appendText(" + ");
            break;
        }
    } else {
        onEqualsButtonPressed();
        break;
    }
case ENTER:
    onEqualsButtonPressed();
    break;
}
```

}

when the ENTER key is pressed, the text previously entered into the TextField simply vanishes.
As I said, every other keyboard onKeyPress event is successfully captured and the calculator works perfectly (including clicking GUI buttons)! This is driving me crazy. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You just need to debug your code. Put some `System.out.println` in different places to see what's happening.

Comment: Are you using `onKeyReleased`?

Comment: The text disappearing upon pressing Enter is definitely not default behavior, and so it must be some other part of your code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: ` if (textFieldDisplayEquation.getText().length() == 0) {
            textFieldDisplayEquation.clear();
            break;` basically says, if there is no text in the TextField, clear it. This code does not seem clear.

Comment: If you are capturing keys via the `TextField`, then you need to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424619/javafx-textfield-how-to-prevent-key-from-getting-typed-in-keypressed-event). Also, text disappearing on its own is definitely something *you* did, like what Itai said.

Comment: Also note that if your scene has a default button, then the "enter" key is going to be stolen by that as well, and that button's `onAction` event will be called.

Comment: The enter key event may be consumed by the `TextField` since `TextField` uses this event to trigger it's own `onAction` event... Clearing the `TextField` in case of an empty `TextField` is simply unnecessary. Furthermore in `case EQUALS:` you add a `break;` to every single if/else clause. You could simply add a single `break;` statement after the outer `if`/`else` and achieve the same effect.

Comment: @Sedrick clearing the text field if length == 0 simply prevents an operator such as "/" from being entered at the beginning of the expression

Comment: @fabian thank you, I wasn't aware of the "break" situation

Comment: @jai I 'm looking into the default button. Thank you

Comment: I don't know if I follow what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It seems that whenever the two textfields are cleared, you have to tell the GridPane to request focus. Having done that, the ENTER key works every time
Below are the relevant code snippets:

```
@FXML
private GridPane root;

 @FXML
    private void onButtonClearClicked() {
        labelMessage.setText("");
        textFieldDisplayEquation.clear();
        textFieldDisplayResult.clear();
        root.requestFocus();
    }
```

Thank you to everyone who took the time to answer or comment!